# nav-pills of bootstrap not working with angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

For the below piece of code if it is nav-tabs it is working fine.It is not working with nav-pills.What is going wrong.Can you please help me.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
        <a class="nav-link " routerLink="dashboard"
        > Dashboard
            
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="dashboard/docter" >Docters</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="dashboard/docter/hello">Hello</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If i change the code to thiss one it is not working..

Dashboard
            
        
    
    
        Docters
    
    
        Hello

Comment: What do you mean, with `nav-pills` it's not working ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI if i change nav-tabs to nav-pills it is not showing button highlightining